# convert into date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to convert a `VARCHAR` into a date and style the output in German fashion:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET C1 = CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,C2,104))


whereas C1 = VARCHAR(15) and C2 = INTEGER.
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: What number *is* `C2` ?

Comment: If `C1` is a `VARCHAR(15)`, why do you update it with a `DATE` datatype?

Comment: I don't know it better :( C2 is YYYYMMDD

Comment: YYYYMMDD is format 112, and you probably was trying to do `convert(date, convert(varchar(8), C2), 112)`

Answer (score 0):

The `int` needs to become a `varchar`, then a `date`, then converted back to a `varchar`:

```
DECLARE @C2 INT = 20160719
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(CAST(@C2 AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE), 104)

--
19.07.2016
```

Answer (score 0):

your string appears to be iso format, so cast it to date, then convert to german format string

```
declare @sdate varchar(15) = '19760229';

select convert(varchar(50),cast(@sdate as datetime), 104);
```

note YYYYMMDD, is a reliable ISO format that I have never had any trouble converting directly to a date